# They made Solomon the son of David king the second time. How?

Tags: 1-chronicles

1 Chronicles 29:22
And they ate and drank before the LORD on that day with great gladness. And they made Solomon the son of David king the second time, and they anointed him as prince for the LORD, and Zadok as priest.

Answer (score 1):

Six chapters earlier in 1 Chronicles 23:1

> When David was old and full of years, he made his son **Solomon** king over Israel.

A parallel account of this twice declarations is in 1 Kings

> 1:34
> There have Zadok the priest and Nathan the prophet anoint him king over Israel. Blow the trumpet and shout, '**Long live King Solomon!**'

> 1:39
> Zadok the priest took the horn of oil from the sacred tent and anointed Solomon. Then they sounded the trumpet and all the people shouted, "**Long live King Solomon!**"

So there was no doubt that Solomon was the king. It served as a warning to Adonijah, Solomon's older brother.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important distinction between what happened at Solomon's first and second anointing.

Solomon's first anointing recorded in 1 Kings 1:32-40 was hurriedly arranged by king David to avert the crowning of Adonijah.

It was very important that Israelite kings rule as vice-regents of God almighty and recognize that fact, 1 Sam 8:7, 8, 24:6, 2 Sam 19:21, 1 Chron 28:5, 2 Chron 9:8, 13:8, Ps 5:2, 44:4.  Thus, kings could not be anointed by mere men but had to be appointed by God and fully recognized by the people.  Thus, it was that Solomon had to have a more complete recognition that he was king by ALL the people.

Thus, the second anointing was to ensure this was the case - all Israel was invited to the ceremony complete with feasting and planned celebrations.

We have an almost identical situation with king Saul many years earlier in 1 Sam 11:14, 15.

Benson arrives at the same conclusion:

> *They made Solomon king the second time* — The first time was, when he was made king during Adonijah’s conspiracy, (1 Kings 1:34,) on which
> occasion it was done in great haste, and in the presence of only a few
> of David’s servants; but now in the presence of all the great men of
> Israel, the princes of the tribes, the captains of thousands and
> hundreds

Similarly, Barnes:

> *King the second time* - Solomon's first appointment was at the time of Adonijah's rebellion (marginal reference). As that appointment was
> hurried and, comparatively speaking, private, David now thought it
> best formally to invest Solomon a second time with the sovereignty, in
> the face of all Israel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and what do we SEE in the letter to the Hebrews that says: Unto them who look for Him (being Jesus) a "Second Time" He will appear with no mention or reference to sin but appearing to them to expedite a complete deliverance to a Salvation being readied to now be revealed in this last of the last of times Amen

Comment: Take a tour of the site to understand how it is different. Use more evidence, reference, and avoid very short answers. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

What it is, Thomas, is these two stories (1K 1, and 1C 29) are reports of the same, not separate events. When you explore the details of each narrative, yes, this is the case, up to and including putting Zadok in the seat of Abiathar. The distinction, instead, is as follows. A number of ANE kingdoms made use of vicegerency as a needful if not somewhat defensive mechanism of state, and also typically in the forms of both viceregency and viceroyalty, which is generally what is meant by coregency. Judah later did, while Israel did not, because Judah was the more vulnerable by far. The duties and functions of a viceregent were of the administrative sort, lower level stuff, but his authority was understood to be unquestioned in such matters, and death of the king would still be expected to see the viceregent accede to regency. The viceroy on the other hand, though also typically a prince, is intended to take on more serious matters of state including warfare. Nebuchadrezzar is believed to have held such an office. And sometimes, as in the case of Solomon, a shift will occur from the lower to the higher level, formally, which is to say advancing from viceregency to viceroyalty. This is what his having been made king a *second* time means.